# Unable to stop the downloading a file when the array is empty using ng-csv

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, export-to-csv

I have a scenario that I want to export an array of json data to csv file by checking a condition like array is empty or not. If the array is not empty I am getting the file with data. But if it is empty I want to prevent the downloading of a file.I am unable to stop the downloading of file.I am using angular 1.5 components and angular material.

HTML:

```
   <md-menu-item>
    <md-button ng-csv="$ctrl.csvProcess()" csv-header="["firstName","lastName","phoneNumber","email"]" filename="Details.csv">Export Selected</md-button>
</md-menu-item>
```

Controller:

```
   csvProcess() {
    if (this.memberSelRows.length === 0) {
        this.toastService.show('Please select Member(s) you would like to Export.', {
            theme: 'warn'
        });
    } else {
        var csvObject = {};
        var csvArray = [];
        angular.forEach(this.memberSelRows, function(value, key) {
            csvObject = {};
            csvObject.firstName = value.firstName
            csvObject.lastName = value.lastName
            csvObject.phoneNumber = value.phoneNumber
            csvObject.email = value.email
            csvArray.push(csvObject)

        })
        return csvArray
    }
}
```

Here **this.memberSelRows** is an array.If it is empty I need to show a toast message and stop the downloading of file. I am getting toast message and downloaded file with empty data. I want to stop downloading. 
Any help is appreciated.